# AngularJS - accessing the directive object inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Let's say that I have define a simple directive:

```
app.directive('someDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function() {

        },
        controller: [function() {
           // Access directive object here...
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Can I access the generated `someDirective` object inside `someDirective`'s controller function? I know that the `this` property reference the directive object inside the `compile` and `template` functions, but i don't know how to access the directive object inside the controller function. Any tricks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, not sure why you'd want too though...

```
app.directive('someDirective', [function() {
    var directiveObject = {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function() {

        },
        controller: [function() {
           // Access directive object here...
           directiveObject.whatever
        }]
    }

    return  directiveObject;
}]);
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a mechanism to extend directives from base-directives.